# Access Qt GUI objects globally

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a source and header file with common functions that I can use in all of my projects with the goal of just having to `#include "functions.h"` to make them work.

The problem is that I do not know how to make the GUI objects for my app accessible. Here is what I have:

**myapp.h**

```
#ifndef myapp_H
#define myapp_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "functions.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class myapp; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class myapp : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  myapp(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
  Ui::myapp *ui;
  ~myapp();

};
#endif // myapp_H
```

**myapp.cpp**

```
#include "myapp.h"

myapp::myapp(QWidget *parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent)
  , ui(new Ui::myapp)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  log(ui->textBrowser, "Some log message");
}
```

**functions.h**

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextBrowser>

void log(QTextBrowser& textBox, QString message);

#endif // FUNCTIONS_H
```

**functions.cpp**

```
#include "functions.h"

void log(QTextBrowser *textBox, QString message) 
{
  qDebug() << message;
  textBox->append(message);
}
```

I think the solution is to make it so that the `ui` is public, and to then pass a reference to the existing `QTextBrowser` object where I want to log the message, but I don't know how I would do that. I would like to be able to run something simple like `log(ui->textBrowser, "Some log message");` from anywhere within my app.

### **EDIT:** I have found the solution. In `functions.h`, I was doing `void log(QTextBrowser& textBox, QString message);` instead of `void log(QTextBrowser* textBox, QString message);`. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. In `functions.h`, I was doing `void log(QTextBrowser& textBox, QString message)` instead of `void log(QTextBrowser* textBox, QString message)`. It works now.

Comment: That is weird, either way should work although you have to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Let's promote loose coupling!  Does it make sense for your entire program to know what the UI object is?  Maybe, but at any scale this becomes a chore to pass this object around.

There's several patterns I could recommend, but for logging, we can simply use the observer pattern.

Your other components that just want to "log" something don't need to know anything about a UI object, Qt stuff, or even what a text browser control is.

Instead, make your logging code a platform in which your UI can register itself with.

So `functions.h` looks more like this:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

#include <functional>

int registerLogEventObserver(const std::function<void(const QString&)>& func);

void unregisterLogEventObserver(int handle); 

void log(const QString& message);

#endif // FUNCTIONS_H
```

And functions.cpp

```
#include "functions.h"
#include <map>

static std::map<int, std::function<void(const QString&)>> g_loggingCallbacks;
static int g_next;

void log(const QString& message) 
{
    for (auto& item : g_loggingCallbacks)
    {
        item.second.callback(message);
    }
}

int registerLogEventObserver(const std::function<void(const QString&)>& func)
{
    int key = g_next++;
    g_loggingCallbacks[key] = func;
    return key;
}

void unregisterLogEventObserver(int key)
{
     g_loggingCallbacks.erase(key);
}
```

Then, when your window is created, it can simply invoke:

```
int _callbackID = registerLogEventObserver([&ui] (const QString& msg) {
    ui->textBrowser->append(msg);
});
```

And when your window closes, it can detach its text browser:

```
unregisterLogEventObserver(_callbackID);
```

Meanwhlie, the code throughout the entire application can just say:

```
log("something special happened");
```

And the content will go to the text control you setup.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not answer my question.

Comment: Any reason not to use signals and slots instead?

Comment: @scopchanov, I would need to add additional lines of code to get signals/slots working. My goal was to make it so that `functions.h` was more plug-and-play and portable.

Comment: Your solution is based on the observer pattern. Signals and slots are the Qt implementation of this pattern. Why not use them, instead of creating a custom implementation.